# how to add text from textbox to split page in windows apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

Ive used a blank page where i have textboxes for a title, subtitle and for a description. Ive added a split page in my app and what i want to do is to be able to get the textbox text from the blank page and add it to the split page where it will be displayed with the details after clicking a button.

Ive checked out how to dynamically add items to a grid view but i want the items to be in the split page format where you click an item on the left side and the description comes to the right side.
Also saw in the splitpage.xaml.cs some TO DO parts where am supposed to bind data and handle selected items i.e

```
// TODO: Assign a bindable group to this.DefaultViewModel["Group"]

// TODO: Assign a collection of bindable items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] 

// TODO: Invoke this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo() with the selected
// item as specified by the value of pageState["SelectedItem"] 

// TODO: Derive a serializable navigation parameter and assign it to pageState["SelectedItem"]
```

My question is how do i do that or at least how to add the textbox data to the split page? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to be more specific.. Do you have one view model for this two split pages?

Comment: There is a vertical scrolling item list made of a listview with a property ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}" and also the details for the selected items are in a scrollviewer whose data context property is: DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}". My question is how to bind those items for them to be dispayed.